# The location of an output .jar file

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have a Scala application made in IntelliJ Idea 12. Although it should be pretty obvious, I didn't find any information about the location of a result (output) **.jar** file which is generated by IDE.

So what's the location?

Comment: If you mean standart artifacts, then should be in `./target/idea_output/artifacts/`

Comment: @AlexIv 1) I don't have this path. 2) I mean an output compiled file -- the result of compilation, like .dll or .exe in Visual Studio.

Comment: You need to make an artifact in the project settings, then click `build artifacts`.

Comment: @AlexIv  where click? how to make them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cmd + ;` opens Project Structure in IDEA. Choose `Artifacts` and make one:

[image]

There you can see the line `Output directory`. Then click `Build artifacts`:

[image]

And here is it:

[image]

Comment: the tab Artifacts is totally empty. What do I do?

Comment: Click on `+` and make one

Comment: how exactly? there are a few options there.

Comment: @MariusKavansky [how to make an artifact](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/)

Comment: that's what I need I believe. However, it's 38 Mb!

Comment: and from now on, I can use this .jar as a library (dependency) in other projects, correct?

Comment: Could you please explain me also: 1) do I create it as "Empty" or "From modules with dependencies"? 2) If the 2nd option then "Create jar from modules" -> "Jar files from libraries" -> a) Extract to target jar b) copy to the output directory and link via manifest  ?